# Why my python code gives "invalid syntax" error?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have following Python function:

```
def LU(A):
    n = A.shape[0]

    k in range(0, n-1):
        if (A[k][k] == 0):
            return 0

        i in range(k+1, n):
            A[i][k] = A[i][k] / A[k][k]

        i in range(k+1, n):
            j in range(k+1, n):
                A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i][k] * A[k][j]

    return A
```

Execution gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4
    k in range(0, n-1):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I get this error on my local machine and in the online interpreter [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3), but [pep8online.com](http://pep8online.com/checkresult) doesn't give any erros.

Does somebody know what is the problem?

Comment: Is that supposed to mean `if k in ..`? Or `for k in ..`...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loops don't begin with `for`.

```
for i in range(x, y):
```

not:

```
i in range(x, y):
```